# How execute system stored procedure sp_refreshview by using Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, linked-server

I need to execute `sp_refreshview` on the other database by using the created linked server.

For example, I have linked server `Demo_LinkedServer`. In the `AdventureWorks` database, I have created a table `Demo_TBL` and on top of the table, created a view named `VW_Demo_TBL`.

Now, I am in a database `Demo_Database`. How I could execute `sp_refreshview` in `AdventureWorks` by using linked server `Demo_LinkedServer`?

First attempt:

```
exec Demo_LinkedServer.AdventureWorks.dbo.sp_refreshview N'dbo.VW_Demo_TBL'.
```

I get the error:

> Server 'Demo_LinkedServer' is not configured for RPC.

Second attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(Demo_LinkedServer, 
               'EXEC sp_refreshview N''dbo.VW_Demo_TBL''')
```

Now I get this error:

> Msg 11528, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 118]
> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC %%TriggerEx(MultiName = @name).LockMatchID(ID = @objid, Exclusive = 1, NameSpaceClass = @ns)' in procedure 'sp_refreshsqlmodule_internal' does not support metadata discovery.

Comment: Are you able to run other stored procedures in the linked server ? using exec command ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the `RPC` and `RPC Out` to `True` in the Linked server Options ?

[image]

Comment: Generally, I cannot do this as they would be the client DBs, but just as a test, I've done this, but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an easy way.
The issue was that I needed to specify the @ViewName for calling the SP sp_refreshview.

**EXEC AdventureWorks.dbo.sp_refreshview @ViewName=N'dbo.VW_Demo_TBL'**

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Here you are not using any linked server. How is this relevant to question ?

Comment: We can use system SPs directly on other DBs without using the linked server. My issue was related to executing the system SP on the other database.